# how to schedule task in windows for asp.net mvc 3 web applications?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC Repeating Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491301/asp-net-mvc-repeating-task)

I am developing MVC 3 web application. I want to do background task using task scheduler in Windows. Is it possible to create a schedule for web application in Windows?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using windows task scheduler, use Quartz.net for creating scheduled background tasks in webapplications.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Comment: with this is that possible http://backgroundworker.codeplex.com/ ???

Comment: It's says it's similar to Quartz, so I think it will.

Comment: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html...this one is licensed one ah??

Comment: sorry http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/license.html in this url they are mentioning about the licence about quartz...

Comment: Yes it's a licence for opensource products

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15981/discussion-between-kanna-and-erwin)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can simply call your webpage with the task scheduler

Example:

```
//Create a new scheduled task to open a browser eg: internet explorer then right
//click properties, in the run window type in with the quotes an example
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.mywebsite.com/something/myactionpage.chtml" 
//If you want to open the page with another browser, just change the first path
```

And the "task" will be the code inside the controller that displays the myactionpage.chtml. Like this:

```
public ActionResult MyActionPage()
{
    // Do some actions
    return this.View();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easy way of running such task is to implement it in your action and then invoke this page trough powershell.
to do it you need to perform next steps:

1) allow powershell to run unsigned scripts. To do it, run powershell and execute:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

2) create your powershell script with next content:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadString("http://yourserver/controller/action") // provide here a correct URL to your action
```

and save it at c:\scripts\task.ps1 for example

3) create a task in scheduler with next command:

```
powershell.exe "c:\scripts\task.ps1"
```

Comment: I want to take some datas from javascript file and then i want to do the background process with task scheduler will it possible

Comment: I can't provide here complete solution for you. But you can reffer to the PowerShell documentation at official site [Scripting with Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx) where you can find plenty of example scripts. Actually PowerShell provides you full access to the .NET runtime, what means that if you can implement your task in C# for example, then you can do the same logic in PS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. But will the scheduled task run on your local machine, is so that can cause problem if your internet is down.

TO create the task. Create a basic schedual task set up the name and how often it will run. THen in the Program/script section enter in

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.yourwebsite.com/backgroundtask"
```

and where I have yoursebsite/backgroundtask, enter in the link to the location of the application page you want.

There are also code library that help with scheduling tasks. Two I have heard of are Quartz: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html
and 
BackgroundWorker: http://backgroundworker.codeplex.com/

Check those out.

Comment: if i given like this     "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.yourwebsite.com/backgroundtask" means will the page open in internet explorer only??

Comment: @kanna Like I said in my answer, the first path is the one that targets the program you want to open and the second one is the path on your website (the target page)

Comment: Yes, what that does is open internet explorer and opens up the webpage specified. If you wanted to open it up in firefox or chrome, you would replace the path to iexplorer with the path to firefox or chrome

Comment: I want to take some datas from javascript file and then i want to do the background process with task scheduler will it possible